# Splitting ZipFile into multiple small chunks and combining Chunks again to create ZipFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to transfer large zip file to remote server. To achieve this, splitting zip file into small chunks and sending these chunks to remote Server. 
When combining all these chunks again and during extraction its showing ZipFile is corrupted. 
Large Text and Image files split and combine correctly. Only Zip files has problem.

The code:

```
public static void SplitFile(string inputFile, int chunkSize, string path)
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (input.Position < input.Length)
        {
            using (Stream output = File.Create(path + "\\" + index))
            {
                int remaining = chunkSize, bytesRead;
                while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0,
                        Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    remaining -= bytesRead;
                }
            }
            index++;                
        }
    }
}

public static void Combine(string directoryPath, string fullFileName) {
    if(File.Exists(fullFileName)) {
        File.Delete(fullFileName);
    }
    using(Stream output = File.Create(fullFileName)) {
        foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath)) {
            using(Stream input = File.OpenRead(file)) {
                input.CopyTo(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t have any ordering on the enumeratefiles.  It’s possible they aren’t being returned in the same order. I’d add some logging and see if that’s the issue

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can use `copy /b part1 + part2 + part3 completefile` at a command prompt to recombine the file. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy).

Answer (score 2):

The below code resolved the ZIP file issue, I dont think it was related to a zip file specifically, I think the combine was not putting the file back together in the right sequence.

Adding a better file name and then an "OrderBy" to the combine appears to have resolved this.

```
public static void SplitFile(string inputFile, int chunkSize, string path)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20 * 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (input.Position < input.Length)
            {
                using (Stream output = File.Create(Path.Combine(path, index.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0'))))
                {
                    int remaining = chunkSize, bytesRead;
                    while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0,
                            Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        remaining -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Combine(string directoryPath, string fullFileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fullFileName))
            File.Delete(fullFileName);

        using (Stream output = File.Create(fullFileName))
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).OrderBy(x => x))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(file))
                    input.CopyTo(output);
            }
                
        
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath))
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
    }
```